# como calcular a media de apenas uma parte de uma coluna Rstudio

Tags: r

Separei apenas uma parte de uma coluna, não consigo trabalhar com esses dados,apenas consigo visualizar de forma separada. Alguem pode me ajudar?! 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente colocar a amostra que você separou em uma variável e tire a média dela

Comment: Bem vindo ao stack overflow português. Para facilitar nossa ajuda, é recomendado seguir o guia de boas resposta como mostrado [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/825/80049).

Comment: Infelizmente, a tua pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R, de modo que as pessoas que querem te ajudar consigam fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Utilize o comando `dput()` com os dados que você deseja tirar a média e poste na sua pergunta, seria muito mais fácil!

Answer (score 1):

Há um problema na importação, seus dados não estão em numéricos.

Criando o exemplo:

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = 1:10, x2 = 11:20)
```

Exemplo de dados não numéricos:

```
data$x1 <- as.factor(data$x1)
mean.default(data$x1[8:9])

Warning message:
In mean.default(data$x3) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Você pode verificar isso através do comando str():

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
$ x1: Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ x2: int  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Correção do armazenamento dos dados se estiver em factor:

```
data$x1 <- as.numeric(levels(data$x1))

mean.default(data$x3[8:9])
[1] 8.5
```